# Inform all kind of errors on production environment through mail same as newrelic does

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want a robust solution for my app in Production environment which would catch all kind of exception and errors and notify me through emails.

Same as Newrelic, but i dont want use new relic instead i want to do same stuff through coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are looking for this gem [exception_notification](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification).